# Multistep shell commands on Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job that has a shell step with following commands. It runs great!

```
sudo yum install python36
virtualenv -p python3 test
source test/bin/activate
<some other command>
```

Now I want to make this into a pipeline. How do I write the same in groovy?
I tried using syntax like this but it fails:

```
stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh 'sudo yum install python36'
            sh 'virtualenv -p python3 test'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you provide the error message or elaborate some more in which way it "fails"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to to execute multiple shell commands you need to wrap them in a pair of three single quotes `'''`:

```
stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh '''
               sudo yum install python36
               virtualenv -p python3 test
               '''
        }
}
```

Comment: what if these commands contain GStrings like `${some}`?

Answer (score 0):

And if your shell commands container GStrings like `${some_str}` use double quotes:

```
stage('Test') {
        steps {
            sh """
               sudo yum install ${some_package}
               virtualenv -p python3 test
               """
        }
}
```